# Saving multi page tiff with jpeg compression

Tags: compression, jpeg

Is there any way to save **multipage tiff** with **JPEG compression** in C#? It seems EncoderValue enum does not have such a value.  any free .net library available to achieve this?

Purpose is to reduce file size of color multipage tiff. Tried with LZW , but still size is not reduced much.all other compression types in enum make images b&w as well.

Comment: Are you aware that LZW is lossless compression, JPEG is lossy?

Comment: yes.But I need to reduce size because of storage limitation.